# OpenId Connect - can client certificate be used for authentication?

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

All the exaples I have seen about OpenID Connect are about using login and password. I have some apps that use client certificate to authenticate at the server. Is this kind of authentication achievable with openid connect?

Answer (score 9):

In fact OpenID Connect does *not* specify how the user is authenticated by a Provider. Instead it specifies a mechanism to convey information about the authenticated user between a Provider and a Relying Party.

It is certainly an option for a Provider to require a client certificate to authenticate its users. There's nothing in the OpenID Connect specification itself that would prohibit that (in that sense it is the same as SAML).

Answer (score 2):

The RFCs [7521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7521) provides a way to use assertions for client authentication.

There are two other RFCs that allow you to use cryptographic methods to authenticate against the authorization server.
Certificates, or more precisely the public key they contain, is used by the authorization server to verify the client assertion:

- Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) 2.0 Profile ([RFC7522](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7522))
- JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile ([RFC7523](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523))

There is also [an ongoing specification draft](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-campbell-oauth-tls-client-auth) that tries to implement a X.509 TLS Authentication for OAuth.